# In 2020, is there an established approach to describe an international site using XML sitemaps?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, internationalization, hreflang, rel-alternate

I've been writing XML Sitemaps for a decade, but I've never before needed to write an XML Sitemap for an **international site**.

It occurs to me that there are three clear approaches (and there may be additional, even better approaches).

**Approach 1 : Single XML Sitemap (primary language URLs *only*, with corresponding pages)**

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>
```

---

**Approach 2 : Single XML Sitemap (*all* relevant URLs, with corresponding pages)**

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>
```

---

**Approach 3: *Multiple* XML Sitemaps (relevant URLs listed for each language, with corresponding pages)**

**`sitemap-en.xml:`**

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>
```

**`sitemap-de.xml:`**

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>
```

---

Much of the advice available on the web is from the first half of the 2010s.

In **2020**, is there an established approach to describe an international site using XML sitemaps?

Comment: At present, I see the merits of **Approach 3**, but - for ease of maintenance - I favour **Approach 2**. At the very least I need to make sure that **Approach 2** is legitimate and that it's _not_ the case that **Approach 1** is actually the standard *single sitemap* approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are all here:

- [Tell Google about localized versions of your page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en#all-method-guidelines)

**Two** of the most important key points to note are:

> Each language version ***must list itself*** as well as all other language versions.

and

> If two pages ***don't both point to each other***, the tags will be ignored. This is so that someone on another site can't arbitrarily
>   create a tag naming itself as an alternative version of one of your
>   pages.

This suggests:

- **Approach 1** is definitely wrong
- **Approach 2** in the question is *almost right*, but needs extending to satisfy all requirements
- **Approach 3** would also be legitimate, *if it were similarly extended* to satisfy all requirements

---

Google gives the following example:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
</url>

<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
</url>

<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
</url>
```

This means an extended version of **Approach 2** will satisfy all requirements:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/example-page-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-1/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-1/" />
</url>

<url>
  <loc>https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/beispielseite-2/" />
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/example-page-2/" />
</url>
```